# I want to animate div when width not 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this problem I want to animate the div from 100% to 0 using velocity js. I want it to animate every time the width not equal 0. The width of the div is updated automatically using setInterval process. This interval process is running forever and will update the width of the div every 3 seconds. The function of velocity js or other animation plugin is to just make it 0% in width.

My code is something like this.

```
    // THIS IS A BIDDING PROCESS

var progressBar = $("#progressBar");
var scenario = 3
var width = 265;
var processDuration = 60000;
var processDelay = 3000;
var time_per_scenario = (processDuration / scenario);
var width_per_processDelay = (width / (processDuration / processDelay));

// Call the  animateProgressBar for first time animation;
animateProgressBar();

setInterval(function(){
    if(scenario != 0) {
         if(time_per_scenario != 0) {
            time_per_scenario -= 1000;
            width -= width_per_processDelay;
         } else {
            scenario--;
            width = 265;
            time_per_scenario = 20000;
            animateProgressBar();
         }
    } else {
        scenario = 3;
    }
}, processDelay);

function animateProgressBar() {

    progressBar.attr("style", "width: " + width);

    console.log("animateProgressBar Again with scenario: " + scenario);

    if(scenario == 0 ) {

        progressBar
        .velocity({ width: width}, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario })
        .velocity({ width: width }, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario, })
        .velocity({ width: width}, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario, });

    } else if(scenario == 1 ){
        progressBar
        .velocity({ width: width }, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario, })
        .velocity({ width: width}, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario, });
    } else {
        progressBar
        .velocity({ width: width }, { duration: 1 })
        .velocity({ width: 0 }, { duration: time_per_scenario });
    }
};
```

The problem with velocity js is that it just animate 1 time even if it is inside the setInterval process it wont do the animation. Why is it happening?

Comment: Please include your code, including your set interval code

Comment: Done including it.

Comment: OK I updated the code. The real code is bit large so I just simplify it for this problem if something missing with my code just tell me.

Comment: put a break point in Chrome debugger here ` if(scenario != 0) {` and see what happening to not call `animateProgressBar` more than once. I think the problem is in there.

Comment: @toddmo My answer below fix the issue however I have having another problem again. Sometime the animation flickers. How can I fix the flickering of the animation. I clear the interval process every 0 width. Is there something I miss?

Comment: Since the flickering is a new issue, you should post a separate question around that issue. Also, remember that you can do a snippet to show and run your html, js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

```js
// THIS IS A BIDDING PROCESS

var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var scenario = 3
var width = 265;
var processDuration = 60000;
var processDelay = 3000;
var time_per_scenario = 20000;
var width_per_processDelay = (width / (processDuration / processDelay));

var process = null;

// Call the  animateProgressBar for the first animation;
animateProgressBar();

setInterval(function(){
    //console.log("time_per_scenario: " + time_per_scenario);
    time_per_scenario -= 3000;
    width -= width_per_processDelay;
},3000);

setInterval(function(){
    if(scenario != 0) {
         if(time_per_scenario <= 0) {
            clearInterval(process);
            scenario--;
            width = 265;
            time_per_scenario = 20000;
            animateProgressBar();
         }
    } else {
        scenario = 3;
    }
}, processDelay);

function animateProgressBar() {
    var widthAnimation = width;
    var width_per_frame = (width / (time_per_scenario / 5));
    //console.log("animateProgressBar Again with scenario: " + scenario);
    process = setInterval(frame, 5);
    var me = this;
    function frame() {
        if (widthAnimation <= 0) {
            clearInterval(process);
        } else {
            widthAnimation = widthAnimation - width_per_frame; 
            progressBar.style.width = widthAnimation + 'px'; 
        }
    }
};
```

```css
#progressBar {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
 <div id="progressBar"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help @toddmo